# Using of Estamator.evaluate() on trained sagemaker tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, amazon-sagemaker

After I've trained and deployed the model with AWS SageMaker, I want to evaluate it on several csv files:

```py
- category-1-eval.csv (~700000 records)
- category-2-eval.csv (~500000 records)
- category-3-eval.csv (~800000 records)
...
```

The right way to do this is with using [Estimator.evaluate()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#evaluate) method, as it is fast.

The problem is - I cannot find the way to restore SageMaker model into Tensorflow Estimator, is it possible?

I've tried to restore a model like this:

```py
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=...,
    hidden_units=[...],
    model_dir="s3://<bucket_name>/checkpoints",
)
```

In AWS SageMaker documentation a different approach is described - [to test the actual endpoint from the Notebook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-model-validation.html) - but it takes to much time and requires a lot of API calls to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you used the built-in Tensorflow container, your model has been saved in Tensorflow Serving format, e.g.:

```
$ tar tfz model.tar.gz
model/
model/1/
model/1/saved_model.pb
model/1/variables/
model/1/variables/variables.index
model/1/variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001
```

You can easily load it with Tensorflow Serving on your local machine, and send it samples to predict. More info at https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving

Comment: Yes, using `model.tar.gz` as a saved model works in my case.

Comment: This was the key point: `predictor= tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model("./model/1/")`

To make `predictor` work with input data this sources helped:

http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/05/14/serve-tensorflow-estimator-with-savedmodel/
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#data_types_for_tfexample
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9554#issuecomment-418876610